# does casting variables change the value?

Tags: java, casting

When casting a Double to Int, lets say

```
 double X = 2.5; 
 int Y = (int)X;
```

can i then use the Double X later, and it still contain the .5? or is the value after the decimal lost forever? can i add onto the Double X, say by .1 increments, and keep casting the value to int Y as a int, but have the int Y only take whole value? say it'll take the value 2, 10 times, and then 3 10 times, and so on.

and does it work the same with arrays? when casting double arrays to int, is the value changed in the array?

thank you.

Comment: TRY it and see what happens :)!

Comment: You *CAN'T* cast double arrays to int arrays!

Answer (score 1):

Casting X to int in a double value X will not remove the floating points from the X.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't change the value, because you are doing it:

```
 int Y = (int)X;
```

So, you're  making things in Y and use for this purpose the variable X, but you never change it. BTW with this can of stuff you can easily write a little program to see what happen.

Answer (score 1):

First off, Double and double mean different things.  Double is a wrapped object and trying to cast is as an Integer will fail.

double and int are primitives, and casting from double to int will not change the value in the double, so what you have should work.

Comment: thank you all, and i am new, i do understand uppercase does matter, i will learn what Double and double mean now :)